# Unnecessary attachment is coming while sending a mail in CI?

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

Hi all i am sending two mail types for my application need. The scene is like this when user approve something i will send a mail to them stating that you approved and in other case after approving one invoice will be generated and it will send as an attachment to the mail.

Now what is happening is these two mail send to the user in a minute a gap or less so for the first mail the attachment is coming unnecessary. And one more thing for suppose another user also approved. By the way invoices are different for different users. But for the second user first user and second user invoices both files are getting attached.

I know these kind of things will happen that's why i am saving the whole mail copy every time which i am sending to any user in database. In database for the first case where i am seeing unnecessary attachment there is no attachment and in the second case where i am seeing two attachments only attachment is there that belongs to user 2 only in the database.

Note: This whole mails are sending using CI email class in LAMP environment.

This below function i am using to send mail. This is a helper function i will call in the whole application where ever i want.

```
function mail_send($to, $email_text_key, $subject_key_values, $message_key_values,$file)
{
    $CI = & get_instance();
    $CI->config->load('email_text');
    //      echo $to;echo $email_text_key;print_r($subject_key_values);print_r($message_key_values);
    $subject = $CI->config->item($email_text_key."_email_subject");
    $message = $CI->config->item($email_text_key."_email_body");// print_r($subject);print_r($message);
    send_mail($to, $subject, $message, $subject_key_values, $message_key_values,$file);
}


function send_mail($to, $subject, $message, $subject_key_values, $message_key_values,$file)
{
    $CI = & get_instance();
    $CI->config->load('email_text');
//  print_r($message_key_values);   
    foreach ( $subject_key_values as $key => $val ) {
        $subject = str_replace ("%$key%", $val, $subject);
    }

    foreach ( $message_key_values as $key => $val ) {
        $message = str_replace ("%$key%", $val, $message);
    }
    $message = str_replace ("%FAQ%", base_url()."index.php/welcome/faq", $message);
    $message = str_replace ("%LOGO%", base_url()."images/logo.png", $message);
    $message = str_replace ("%LOGO%", base_url()."images/Icon.ico", $message);
    $CI->load->library('email');

    $CI->email->from($CI->config->item('from_email'), $CI->config->item('from_email_name'));
    $CI->email->to($to);

    $CI->email->subject($subject);
    $CI->email->message($message);
    if($file !='') {
    $CI->email->attach($file);
    $file_type='pdf';
    $file_size = filesize($file);
    $fp = fopen($file,'r');
    $content = fread($fp,$file_size);
    $content = addslashes($content);
    fclose($fp);
    $CI->email->send();
    } else {
     $CI->email->send();
    }
    //make mail copied
    $CI->load->model('email_model');
    $user_data = array(
                        'to_email' =>$to,
                        'subject' =>$subject,
                        'message' =>$message,
                        'date_time' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
                        'file_name' =>$file,
                        'file_type' =>$file_type,
                        'file_size' =>$file_size,
                        'content' =>$content,
                    );
    $CI->email_model->make_email_copy($user_data);              
}
```

Note: Please check my code where i am attaching file to mail in if and else condition.

Comment: How do you call your `send_mail` function?  when there is no file is the called by adding `''`? Or a null value?

Comment: by adding $file = ''; when i am calling email_send only.....

Comment: Try adding `$CI->email->clear();` after `$CI->load->library('email');`

Comment: i added as you said no it's not working.........

Comment: i am trying that from before only but now i got it to clear attachments we need to pass TRUE to clear method in email class$CI->email->clear(TRUE);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$this->email->clear()

Initializes all the email variables to an empty state. This function is intended for use if you run the email sending function in a loop, permitting the data to be reset between cycles.

```
foreach ($list as $name => $address)
{
    $this->email->clear();

    $this->email->to($address);
    $this->email->from('your@example.com');
    $this->email->subject('Here is your info '.$name);
    $this->email->message('Hi '.$name.' Here is the info you requested.');
    $this->email->send();
}
```

If you set the parameter to TRUE any attachments will be cleared as well:

```
$this->email->clear(TRUE);
```